# Is there a way to find test cases that are not part of any test suite?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, microsoft-test-manager

The way that we use Microsoft Test Manager means that we want every test case to be included in at least one test suite. However, we have (manually) discovered some test cases that are not part of any test suite. Finding these by hand is very time consuming.

Therefore: Is there any way to find all test cases that are not part of any test suite?

(We're using Microsoft Test Manager 2012/2013.)

Comment: Which TFS version are you using?

Comment: @Elena The version that comes with Visual Studio 2012

Comment: I'm not asking about the version of Team Explorer (that comes with  Visual Studio) but about the version of Team Foundation Server, e.g. you can use Visual Studio 2012 with both versions of TFS (2012 and 2013). Since you wrote "We're using Microsoft Test Manager 2012/2013" I suppose you are using TFS 2012, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it using *MTM* (no matter which version you are using).

Using *TFS 2012* the only way is to use *TFS-API*, here a short example how to check if a particular *Test Case* is a part of any *Test Suite*:

```cs
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;

// Current user credentials will be used to access to TFS
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(<TFS Url>));
tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

ITestManagementService testManagementService = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
ITestManagementTeamProject  teamProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(<team project name>);

// Get all Test Suites your Test Case belongs to
// (Across all Test Plans in the Team Project)
ITestSuiteCollection testSuites = teamProject.TestSuites.ReferencingTestCase(<test case id>);
bool doesItBelongToAnyTestSuite = testSuites.Any();
```

If you would use *TFS 2013* it will be possible to achieve this using *Work Item* queries since *Test Plan* and *Test Suite* become *Work Items* with *TFS 2013 **Update 3*** ([RC was released on 2. July 2014](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2014-jul-2-vs)).